# UILabel get font size dynamically - swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview

I have a UILabel -> txtLabel and UITextView -> txtView in my app
I have values as below

```
txtLabel.text = "The best preparation for tomorrow is doing best today" 
txtView.text = "iOS Text View"
//Font size is 12 for both 
// I have minimum font size for label as 7 so for smaller devices that can 
   scale down till 7 and display entire label text in single line
```

My requirement is to have single line label and single line textView with same font sizes. 
However this runs fine in my iOS 7 simulator.

But in iPhone SE, when i run this I get small font for label (say 8) and textView font remains same 12

My question is: How to change font size of textView depending on new scaled font size of label?

e.g: in iPhone SE simulator, my label scales down to 7 . So i should have my textView size also set to be 7
in iPhone7, size 12 will fit screen so textView size also should be 12

I cannot have single label/ single text view to fit entire content so the font remains same. It needs to be one separate label and one separate textview because i do have other fields in between and this possibility is ruled out

Pls advice

Comment: you may set attributed string to your label, and use system font to handle font size automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving constant value, give font size according to the self.view

```
txtLabel.font = UIFont(name: "ProximaNova-Regular", size: self.view.frame.size.height/40 )
```